# How to display text when Button is pressed on Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I was wondering how I could make the button I've created on my platform using Kivy, display text when pressed. I want it to display text on the kivy window, not in my integrated terminal. So I was wondering if anyone could help me with that. I want it to display a random dare from my txt file that I have.

Here is my code:

```
Label:
    text: "Truth or Dare?"
TextInput:
    hint_text: "Two Things To Try: Truth or Dare"
Button:
    text: "Generate"
    on_press: #I dont know what to do here
ScrollView:
Label:
```

If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually i suggest you to use ScreenManager with kivy.So you can easily use Properties.

But for this solution you can use that:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
kv_string = """
#:import choice random.choice
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Label:
        id: mylabel
        text: "Truth or Dare?"
    TextInput:
        id: myinput
        hint_text: "Two Things To Try: Truth or Dare"
    Button:
        text: "Generate"
        on_release: root.ids.mylabel.text = choice(app.my_list)
"""
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        with open('asd.txt', 'r') as mytxt:
            self.my_list = mytxt.readlines()
        return Builder.load_string(kv_string)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```